# How to redirect from one jsp to another jsp in Spring MVC when it satisfies the condition of another variable

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, spring-mvc

Working on Spring MVC where i want to redirect a page from one JSP to another when the condition satisfies.

1. If the column experience is greater than 3 then it has to redirect to the another JSP page(Current JSP page: addEmployee to insureEmployee JSP page)
2. When the value is lesser than 3 then it has to normally store the data to the database.
3. I have 2 tables...So when the experience is more than 3 years then it has to redirect to the new JSP and once i submit the data must be stored in the database(Secondary table) or else when experience is lesser than 3 then it has to save to the Primary table database
4. I just want to redirect to another JSP when i enter value  more than 3 in the experience column
5. I have posted my Controller class and JSP codes

Controller of Employee Class:

```
   package com.dineshonjava.controller;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.validation.Valid;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import com.dineshonjava.bean.EmployeeBean;
    import com.dineshonjava.model.Employee;
    import com.dineshonjava.service.EmployeeService;
    @Controller
    public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@Valid  @ModelAttribute("command") EmployeeBean employeeBean, 
                BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()){

                return new ModelAndView("addEmployee");
            }

            Employee employee = prepareModel(employeeBean);
            employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
            return new ModelAndView("displayEmployee",model);
            }
        @RequestMapping(value = "/saved", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView savedEmployee(@Valid  @ModelAttribute("command") EmployeeBean employeeBean, 
                BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()){

                return new ModelAndView("addEmployee");
            }
            Employee employee = prepareModel(employeeBean);
            employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
            return new ModelAndView("displayEmployee",model);
        }
        @RequestMapping(value="/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView listEmployees() {
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
            return new ModelAndView("employeesList", model);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView addEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute("command")  EmployeeBean employeeBean,
                BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()){

                return new ModelAndView("addEmployee");
            }
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
            return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", model);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView welcome() {
            return new ModelAndView("index");
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/sub", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView Edit() {
            return new ModelAndView("displayEmployee");
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView editEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command")  EmployeeBean employeeBean,
                BindingResult result) {
            employeeService.deleteEmployee(prepareModel(employeeBean));
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("employee", null);
            model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
            return new ModelAndView("displayEmployee", model);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView deleteEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute("command")  EmployeeBean employeeBean,
                BindingResult result) {
          if(result.hasErrors()){
                 Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                 model.put("employee", prepareEmployeeBean(employeeService.getEmployee(employeeBean.getId())));
                  model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
                return new ModelAndView("editEmployee", model);
            }
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("employee", prepareEmployeeBean(employeeService.getEmployee(employeeBean.getId())));
            model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
            return new ModelAndView("displayEmployee", model);
        }

        private Employee prepareModel(EmployeeBean employeeBean){
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setAddress(employeeBean.getAddress());
            employee.setAge(employeeBean.getAge());
            employee.setName(employeeBean.getName());
            employee.setSalary(employeeBean.getSalary());
            employee.setId(employeeBean.getId());
            employee.setBae(employeeBean.getBae());
            employee.setExperience(employeeBean.getExperience());
            employee.setEmail(employeeBean.getEmail());
            employee.setPassword(employeeBean.getPassword());

            employeeBean.setId(null);
            return employee;
        }
        private List<EmployeeBean> prepareListofBean(List<Employee> employees){
            List<EmployeeBean> beans = null;
            if(employees != null && !employees.isEmpty()){
                beans = new ArrayList<EmployeeBean>();
                EmployeeBean bean = null;
                for(Employee employee : employees){
                    bean = new EmployeeBean();
                    bean.setName(employee.getName());
                    bean.setId(employee.getId());
                    bean.setAddress(employee.getAddress());
                    bean.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
                    bean.setAge(employee.getAge());
                    bean.setBae(employee.getBae());
                    bean.setExperience(employee.getExperience());
                    bean.setEmail(employee.getEmail());
                    bean.setPassword(employee.getPassword());

                    beans.add(bean);
                }
            }
            return beans;
        }
        private EmployeeBean prepareEmployeeBean(Employee employee){
            EmployeeBean bean = new EmployeeBean();
            bean.setAddress(employee.getAddress());
            bean.setAge(employee.getAge());
            bean.setName(employee.getName());
            bean.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
            bean.setId(employee.getId());
            bean.setBae(employee.getBae());
            bean.setExperience(employee.getExperience());
            bean.setEmail(employee.getEmail());
            bean.setPassword(employee.getPassword());

            return bean;
        }
    }





 Controller of Worker Class:
```

> ```
> package com.dineshonjava.controller;
> import java.util.ArrayList;
> import java.util.HashMap;
> import java.util.List;
> import java.util.Map;
> import javax.validation.Valid;
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
> import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
> import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;    import com.dineshonjava.bean.WorkerBean;
> import com.dineshonjava.model.Worker;
> import com.dineshonjava.service.WorkerService;
> @Controller
> public class  WorkerController {
> @Autowired
> private WorkerService workService;
> @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
> public ModelAndView saveWorker(@Valid  @ModelAttribute("command") WorkerBean workBean, 
>           BindingResult result) {
> if(result.hasErrors()){
>
>           return new ModelAndView("");
>       }
>
>       Worker work = prepareModel(workBean);
>       workService.addWorker(work);
>       Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
>       model.put("works",  prepareListofBean(workService.listWorkers()));
>       return new ModelAndView("",model);
>       }
>
> @RequestMapping(value = "/added", method = RequestMethod.GET)
> public ModelAndView added() {
>   return new ModelAndView("insureEmployee");
> }
> @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
>   public ModelAndView savedWorker(@Valid  @ModelAttribute("command") WorkerBean workBean, 
>           BindingResult result) {
> if(result.hasErrors()){
>
>           return new ModelAndView("");
>       }
>         Worker work = prepareModel(workBean);
>         workService.addWorker(work);
>       Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
>       model.put("works",  prepareListofBean(workService.listWorkers()));
>       return new ModelAndView("",model);
>   }
>   @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
>   public ModelAndView listWorker() {
>       Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
>       model.put("works",  prepareListofBean(workService.listWorkers()));
>       return new ModelAndView("", model);
>   }
>
>   @RequestMapping(value = "/insure", method = RequestMethod.GET)
>   public ModelAndView addWorker(@Valid @ModelAttribute("command")  WorkerBean workBean,
>           BindingResult result) {
> if(result.hasErrors()){
>
>           return new ModelAndView("insureEmployee");
>       }
>       Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
>       model.put("works",  prepareListofBean(workService.listWorkers()));
>       return new ModelAndView("insureEmployee", model);
>   }
>
>   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
>   public ModelAndView editEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command")  WorkerBean workBean,
>           BindingResult result) {
>       workService.deleteWorker(prepareModel(workBean));
>       Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
>       model.put("work", null);
>       model.put("works",  prepareListofBean(workService.listWorkers()));
>       return new ModelAndView("", model);
>   }
>
>   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
>   public ModelAndView deleteWork(@Valid @ModelAttribute("command")  Worker workBean,
>           BindingResult result) {
>       if(result.hasErrors()){
>            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
>            model.put("work", prepareWorkerBean(workService.getWorker(workBean.getId())));
>             model.put("works",  prepareListofBean(workService.listWorkers()));
>           return new ModelAndView("", model);
>       }
>       Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
>       model.put("work", prepareWorkerBean(workService.getWorker(workBean.getId())));
>       model.put("works",  prepareListofBean(workService.listWorkers()));
>       return new ModelAndView("", model);
>   }
>
>   private Worker prepareModel(WorkerBean workBean){
>       Worker work = new Worker();
>       work.setPhone(workBean.getPhone());
>       work.setAccno(workBean.getAccno());
>       work.setId(workBean.getId());
>       workBean.setId(null);
>       return work;
>   }
>   private List<WorkerBean> prepareListofBean(List<Worker> work){
>       List<WorkerBean> beans = null;
>       if(work != null && !work.isEmpty()){
>           beans = new ArrayList<WorkerBean>();
>           WorkerBean bean = null;
>           for(Worker worker : work){
>               bean = new WorkerBean();
>
>               bean.setId(worker.getId());
>               bean.setPhone(worker.getPhone());
>                 bean.setAccno(worker.getAccno());
>
>               beans.add(bean);
>           }
>       }
>       return beans;
>   }
>
>   private WorkerBean prepareWorkerBean(Worker work){
>       WorkerBean bean = new WorkerBean();
>
>       bean.setId(work.getId());
>       bean.setPhone(work.getPhone());
>       bean.setAccno(work.getAccno());
>
>       return bean;
>   }
> }
> ```

addEmployee JSP file which has to be redirected:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<style>
.error {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<body>
    <h2>Add Employee Data</h2>
    <form:form method="POST" action="/sdnext/save.html">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" width="20%">EmployeeID:</td>
                <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="id"
                        readonly="true" size="30" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" width="20%">Name:</td>
                <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="name" size="30" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" width="20%">Age:</td>
                <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="age" size="30" /></td>
                <td align="left"><form:errors path="age" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" width="20%">salary:</td>
                <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="salary"
                        size="30" /></td>
                <td align="left"><form:errors path="salary" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" width="20%">Address:</td>
                <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="address"
                        size="30" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="address" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" width="20%">Bae:</td>
                <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="bae" size="30" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="bae" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" width="20%">Experience:</td>
                <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="experience" id="experience"
                        size="30" onblur="checkExperience()"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="experience" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" width="20%">Email:</td>
                <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="email" size="30" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="email" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><form:password path="password" size="30" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>


    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

insureEmployee JSP file (which gets redirect to this page):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>


<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body> 
<form:form method="POST" action="/sdnext/insure.html" >
                 <table> <tr>
             <tr>
                <td align="left" width="20%">Phone:</td>
                <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="phone" size="30" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="phone" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Account Number:</td>
                <td><form:password path="accno" size="30" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="accno" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
            </tr>
            </table>

</form:form>
</body>
</html>


InsureEmployee where redirected page comes here:
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>


<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body> 
<form:form method="POST" action="/sdnext/insure.html" >
                 <table> <tr>
             <tr>
                <td align="left" width="20%">Phone:</td>
                <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="phone" size="30" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="phone" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Account Number:</td>
                <td><form:password path="accno" size="30" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="accno" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
            </tr>
            </table>

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is way too much code. Please post only the **relevant** code and relevant HTML (**Rendered** HTML **not** the code that generates it) preferably in a working snippet to demonstrate the issue you have with your current evaluation of your before mentioned conditions/logic so we can see what might be the problem. Please see [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can check the condition before the return statement, But you need to have two redirects one for the greater than 3 and another one for the less than 3.

Comment: I think it's important you also understand that you're simply choosing different views to return. Redirect would imply something else.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is

```
if(variable > 3){
   return new ModelAndView("return to greater than 3 page");
}else{
 return new ModelAndView("return to same page");
}
```

You will need to redirect to either to the same page or any other because, of the method return type.

Comment: Is there any possibility than i can edit in my JSP page using Javascript or any?Can i use that in controller?  :-(

Comment: Means I didn't get that one. Edit the JSP for what?

Comment: If there are two JSP files...say hi.jsp and hello.jsp..In hi i have 3 columns...(id,name,experience).If i give experience as more than 3, then it has to redirect to hello.jsp page.Or when i give lesser value than 3, then it has to store the data normally in the database. Am I clear to you bro..sorry if it's not understandable to you

Comment: You can check that using the jquery You can get the value of the field using **$("#idofield").val() >= 3** then set **window.location ="hello.jsp"**. Also you can check that on the blur event of textbox used for the experience.